# Filter a text file output of a batch file to get a specific line and output to text

Tags: batch-file, filter, txt

I would like to filter the output of `ipconfig /all` 
to only save what is between
`Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :`
and `Node`
extract it and output it to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=11* delims= " %%A IN (`ipconfig /all ^| findstr /c:"Primary Dns Suffix"`) DO ECHO %%B> netinfo.txt
```

This will output everything on the `Primary Dns Suffix` line beyond `Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :` . %%B is everything beyond the 11th space there, effectively doing exactly as you want.

Two things to keep in mind: If you're using this command directly on the command line, change %%A and %%B to %A and %B respectively.
Also, the output will show `ECHO is on.` if there is no `Primary Dns Suffix`.

Comment: I would like to add that this doesn't seem to work for me in cmd, i need a cmd (not powershell) version please.

```%%A was unexpected at this time.```

Comment: @NicholasStockton Read my entire answer. This IS meant for cmd, and I addressed your issue. Simply change %%A and %%B to %A and %B, like I stated before.

In an actual `batch-file` %%A and %%B would be used instead.